# Express + bodyParser.json() + Postman, req.body is empty

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, body-parser

When using the following:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.post('/test', bodyParser.json(), function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body);
});

var port = 4040;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at port: %s', port);
});
```

and the following post from Postman:

[image]

I get an empty response.  I've followed a lot of threads on using bodyParser.json() and for some reason I'm still receiving an empty object in response.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make `bodyParser.json` works you should provide `Content-Type` header with value `application/json` in your requests.

Answer (score 5):

A safer way to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) would be to apply it as middleware for the entire app. The code will have to be refactored in this manner:

```
// Permit the app to parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Use body-parser as middleware for the app.
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

When you make a request on Postman, make sure to select the `x-www-form-urlencoded` tab as opposed to the `raw` tab.

Comment: I'm familiar with the middleware pattern, just wanted to keep things as simple as possible in this example.  x-ww-form-urlencoded did work, though I chose the other option as the answer because the json blob was my preferred means of sending the data.

Comment: using [ x-www-form-urlencoded ] worked for me. I was using form data which was causing error.

Comment: The reference of the answer above, can match with https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#examples